# when using max with union all the select return first row value as result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT max(t.a),t.b 
from(
 SELECT 10 as a,1 as b,1 as c 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 20,2,1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 30,3,2  
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 40,4,2 ) as t 
 order by b desc;
```

result = 40,1,1

result needed = 40,4,2
20,2,1
result to return group by column c get the max of a and the b column with it .

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need the first row when ordered:

```
select a, b
from (
 select 10 as a,1 as b 
 union all
 select 20,2 
 union all
 select 30,3  
 union all
 select 40,4 
) as t 
order by b desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I think OP wants `order by a desc`

Comment: They have order by `b` in their query, either a or b produces same result.

Comment: The result is the same. The logic is not. Clearly OP wants the biggest `a` hence `max(t.a)`....

Comment: Clearly? Is there something in the question I'm missing perhaps? With their results having 1 for `b` and wanting `4` it seems the reverse to me.

Answer (score 1):

The query in the questions seems incorrect, it will fail with sql_mode=only_full_group_by enabled, which I strongly recommended  to be enabled.

If you want to handle ties , you could use:

```
select a,b
from  (  select a,
                b,
                row_number() over (order by a desc ) as rn
         from ( SELECT 10 as a,1 as b 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 20,2 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 30,3  
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 40,4 
              ) x
    ) xx
where rn=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/bvCKF0od

On MySQL < 8.0, to handle ties you could use:

```
select x.a,
       x.b
from ( SELECT 10 as a,1 as b 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 20,2 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 30,3  
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 40,4 
     ) x
inner join (select max(a) as a
            from ( SELECT 10 as a,1 as b 
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 20,2 
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 30,3  
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 40,4 
                  ) xx
           )as tbl on tbl.a=x.a;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/_e97v_zi

Comment: That of course works only in MySQL 8+

Comment: @juergend fair enough, updated with a solution for older MySQL versions, though we know that MySQL 5.7 will reach EOL on October 2023.

Comment: for first one getting error ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by a desc) as rn

Comment: @raj probably your MySQL version is older than 8 , in that case windows functions aren't supported.